# Connecting Queue manager with multiple threads

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

We are trying to publish messages on a topic using multiple connection handles for a queue manager. We are using threads for this.
    However when we use fifty threads the messages are properly pulbished on to the topic but as we go on increasing the threads, to say 500, we get the following reason codes 2071,2012,2538 for some threads and then the program crashes giving reason code as 2059 for remaining threads

```
I thought that may be due to restriction on the number of connection handle we are getting these errors. So I tried
1.  adding channels stanza to qm.ini file
        CHANNELS:
        MaxChannels=<number>
        MaxActiveChannels=<number> 

2.  altering MAXHANDS of my queuemanager to 2000


But found no luck in the above approaches.
Kindly help me in solving this issue.

PS. We have created our own Library for calling websphere MQ API.

Thanks,
Mandar.
```

Comment: It looks like resource contention. Did you check the qmgr error logs? Did you check for any FFST? Is the qmgr still running after all these errors?

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you try increasing the Shared Conversation (SHARECNV) value on the server connection channel you are using for connecting to queue manager.

In runmqsc shell run the following command to alter the SHARECNV for the channel.

```
alter channel <your SVRCONN channel name> chltype(SVRCONN) sharecnv(<say 100>)
```